# Tapping on button dismisses the keyboard instead of calling its TouchUpInside event

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, keyboard, iqkeyboardmanager

I have a `ViewController` with single `textfield` and one `button` , when I start editing text in `textfield`,Keyboard pops up.

Now if I tap on `button`, it closes the keyboard first then on second tap the `button's` `touchupinside` event gets fired.

That means if I want to tap on `button` I need to tap it twice i.e; first tap closes the keyboard and then only I can tap on the `button`.

I would like to be able to tap on `button` without closing the `keyboard`.
I am also using `IQKeyboardManager` , don't know if it can be the cause of such behaviour.

This is my IQKeyboardManager code

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().touchResignedGestureIgnoreClasses = [UINavigationBar.self,UIControl.self
```

Comment: if you want to perform the action using next button or else , I partially understand your question

Comment: Please post your source code, so that problem can be identified

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that is a simple button and i want to perform the action using button only , if keyboard is not opened its action is working perfectly but if we have keyboard open then tapping on it is not calling that action.

Comment: it doesn't matter what code i have written in button action if it not being called

Comment: you are doing something wrong while implementing IQKeyboardManager